# Problem regarding downloading files in folders and subfolders

Tags: c#

I am stuck and asking for your help, trying to make a software that check a txt file which is this format with CRC information and download the files inside that txt. These is just an example with same hash but in reality have different name, hash and size.

```
[FOLDER/FILE]               [HASH]   [FILESIZE]       

./file1.dat                 f926038f 54 
./Folder/file2.dat          f926038f 54
./Folder/Subfolder/file3.dat f926038f 54
```

after I generate this type of information, I use this code to read where is the file...

```
private static void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(new WebClient().OpenRead(Import.ServerURL + Import.PatchlistName));
            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                ListProcessor.AddFile(streamReader.ReadLine());
        }
```

and these code to check the list of that file and write them in current folder

```
internal class ListProcessor
    {
        public static void AddFile(string File) => Import.Files.Add(new Import.File()
        {
            Name = File.Split(' ')[0],
            Hash = File.Split(' ')[1],
            Size = Convert.ToInt64(File.Split(' ')[2])
        });
    }
```

the problem is that files outside of any folders or subfolders they are downloading perfectly, but inside any folder or subfolder the download does not work.

PS: This is the order from where it starts:

Main.cs

```
private void Btn_Run_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.Btn_Run.Enabled)
        return;
    ListDownloader.DownloadList();
}
```

ListDownloader.cs

```
internal class ListDownloader
    {
        public static void DownloadList()
        {
            Common.ChangeStatus("LISTDOWNLOAD");
            Common.DisableStart();
            BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(ListDownloader.backgroundWorker_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(ListDownloader.backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            
            if (backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                int num = (int) MessageBox.Show(Texts.GetText("UNKNOWNERROR", (object) "DownloadList isBusy"));
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else
                backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private static void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(new WebClient().OpenRead(Import.ServerURL + Import.PatchlistName));
            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                ListProcessor.AddFile(streamReader.ReadLine());
        }

        private static void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
          FileChecker.CheckFiles();
        }
    }
```

FileChecker.cs

```
internal class FileChecker
    {
        private static BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

        public static void CheckFiles()
        {
            FileChecker.backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            FileChecker.backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(FileChecker.backgroundWorker_DoWork);
            FileChecker.backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(FileChecker.backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged);
            FileChecker.backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(FileChecker.backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            
            if (FileChecker.backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                int num = (int) MessageBox.Show(Texts.GetText("UNKNOWNERROR", (object) "CheckFiles isBusy"));
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else
                FileChecker.backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private static void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Import.File file in Import.Files)
            {
                Import.fullSize += file.Size;
                FileChecker.backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, (object) Path.GetFileName(file.Name));
                
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(file.Name) || string.Compare(Common.GetHash(file.Name), file.Hash) != 0)
                {
                    Import.OldFiles.Add(file.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    Import.completeSize += file.Size;
                    FileChecker.backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(1);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ProgressPercentage == 0)
            {
                Common.ChangeStatus("CHECKFILE", e.UserState.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                Common.UpdateCompleteProgress(Computer.Compute(Import.completeSize));
                Common.UpdateCurrentProgress(Computer.Compute(Import.completeSize), 0.0);
            }
        }

        private static void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            FileDownloader.DownloadFile();
        }

        private enum State
        {
            REPORT_NAME,
            REPORT_PROGRESS,
        }
    }
```

and FileDownloader.cs

```
internal class FileDownloader
    {
        private static int curFile;
        private static long lastBytes;
        private static long currentBytes;
        private static Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        public static void DownloadFile()
        {
            if (Import.OldFiles.Count <= 0)
            {
                Common.ChangeStatus("CHECKCOMPLETE");
                Common.UpdateCurrentProgress(100L, 0.0);
                Common.UpdateCompleteProgress(100L);
                Starter.Start();
            }
            else if (FileDownloader.curFile >= Import.OldFiles.Count)
            {
                Common.ChangeStatus("DOWNLOADCOMPLETE");
                Common.UpdateCurrentProgress(100L, 0.0);
                Common.UpdateCompleteProgress(100L);
                Starter.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                if (Import.OldFiles[FileDownloader.curFile].Contains("/"))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(Import.OldFiles[FileDownloader.curFile]));
                
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(FileDownloader.webClient_DownloadProgressChanged);
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(FileDownloader.webClient_DownloadFileCompleted);
                FileDownloader.stopWatch.Start();
                Common.ChangeStatus("DOWNLOADFILE", Import.OldFiles[FileDownloader.curFile]);
                webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(Import.ServerURL + Import.OldFiles[FileDownloader.curFile]), Import.OldFiles[FileDownloader.curFile]);
            }
        }

        private static void webClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FileDownloader.currentBytes = FileDownloader.lastBytes + e.BytesReceived;
            Common.UpdateCompleteProgress(Computer.Compute(Import.completeSize + FileDownloader.currentBytes));
            Common.UpdateCurrentProgress((long) e.ProgressPercentage, Computer.ComputeDownloadSpeed((double) e.BytesReceived, FileDownloader.stopWatch));
        }

        private static void webClient_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            FileDownloader.lastBytes = FileDownloader.currentBytes;
            Common.UpdateCurrentProgress(100L, 0.0);
            ++FileDownloader.curFile;
            FileDownloader.stopWatch.Reset();
            FileDownloader.DownloadFile();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The files all have the same name file.data and you are putting in same folder so you only get one copy of each filename.

Comment: This was just an example, they have different names, hash and size

Comment: Then the pathnames are not correct for the files.

Comment: Relative paths are a bad idea.  You *must* store the complete path, c:/foo/bar/baz.txt.  Use Path.GetFullPath() if necessary.  Do keep in mind that filenames may contain a space, consider vbTab instead.

Comment: Pathnames are exactly the same, i have a bunch of files inside root folder which are downloading correctly, the update server and the client have the same folders but don't download the files in folders or subfolders, even if i delete them still don't work

Comment: Does "the download does not work" mean that it gives an error message?

Comment: No, it's simply don't download, no error no nothing, even if the folder is not in the client path, does not create it, just pass it

Comment: Does "download the files" mean download from a web server on the internet? (Some people use "download" to also mean "copy from another directory on the same computer.")

Comment: Yes, downloading from a web server